# How to retrieve multiple results with one Httppost request?

Tags: php, android

I‘m trying to use httppost to send data from Android phone to php server. The connection is okay.
On the php side I use echo to specify the response. example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
echo "This is the response.";
}
?>
```

The tricky thing here is what if I want to add multiple data to the same request which will retrieve a multiple results not only one response.
This is my java code:

```
Httpclient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
Httppost hp = new HttpPost("link");
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "Mansour"));
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Age", "12"));
    try{
        hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
        hr = hc.execute(hp);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hr.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = null;
        String compare;
        while((compare = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(compare);
        }
        // Toast the response
        Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create Object class with multiple data u want to send and serialize it to json. Gson would be perfect for it. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Hope it's useful ;)

Comment: From the first begining I was avoiding using JSON because I don‘t feel comfortable dealing with it. Is it possible to do the same thing with List<NameValuePair> as in my above code?